# Access protected S3 bucket using CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a S3 bucket that can be accessed only using signed urls. Until now i generated signed urls using GeneratePresignedUrlRequest (Java). 
Now i want to access my bucket through CloudFront. The question is how i generate a signed url in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all in the docs.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls-overview.html

You also have to properly configure the interaction between Cloudfront and S3.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html

If you are a programmer, you will also find it interesting and important that Cloudfront uses a different set of base64 rules than S3.  Instead of percent-encoding the unsafe characters `+ = /` in a signed url, Cloudfront expects them to be transliterated into `-_~` respectively.